# Implementing ipod playback

Tags: ios, playback, ipod

How can I let ipod playback continue when my app is on the run?

Answer (score 4):

At startup you need to init an `AudioSession` by calling

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

and then set your audio category to `kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound`, like so

```
UInt32  sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

Comment: I thank you for showing concern but can you be a little more specific of what to do... i'm sort of a newbie..... i'll be thankful

Comment: sure, I added a link to some code.

Comment: looks like there's an errant space in "kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory" - but otherwise this worked great, even while doing remoteio and avaudioplayer at the same time.

Comment: Fixed, happy to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that it has nothing to do with your app (i.e. a special background service runs for the ipod), but i could be wrong...